# Get vector layers of self.iface.legendInterface()

Tags: pyqgis, vector-layer

I have an application which I **did not** use qgisMapComboboxes; I used simple QComboBox.

without changing the combobox type, how can I get only vector layers in `VectorLayers = iface.legendInterface().layers()` before my iteration and combobox layer manipulation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use something like the following to only get vector layers:

```
VectorLayers = [layer for layer in iface.legendInterface().layers() if layer.type() == QgsMapLayer.VectorLayer]
```

Comment: @AfshinSalehi - Most welcome, glad it helped :)